# Index Error on Python List Lab

Tags: python, python-3.x

My computer science teacher assigned a lab where we need to create a loop that will create 50 lists and add 1 to the value of each list for each time the number is inputted. We are not allowed to have one list and just use the count function to accomplish this task (for some strange reason).

Basically, I want this code to work, but in the manner that the teacher wants:

```
l_a=[]

for num in range(0,10):
    y=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    l_a.append(y)

print(l_a)

for x in range(0,51):
    z=(l_a.count(x))
    if z==1:
        print("There is "+str(z)+" "+str(x)+".")
    if z>1:
        print("There are "+str(z)+" "+str(x)+"'s.")
```

Here is the code I have created so far:

```
list=[]

for index in range(0,51):
    list[index]=0

for num in range(0,51):
    y=(int)(input("Enter a number: "))
    list[y]+=1
```

I get the following error:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Harrison

Comment: `list[index]=0` ---> `list.append(0)`

Comment: So you just want lists of all zeroes, with lengths from 0-50? Look into list multiplication `[0] * 4` -> `[0, 0, 0, 0]`.  Be careful doing it with mutable elements though.

Comment: You should avoid reserved words such as `list` when naming variables.

Comment: With a blank list, you don't have any index existing -- you are treating it like adding dictionary inputs. All you need to do is append the zeros to the list and they'll be positional. You could do this in one line as well, something like `[0 for x in range(0,51)]`

Comment: use dictionary if you want to keep both index and initialization value

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an index out of range is becuase when stating a list

```
lst = []
```

You are actually creating a list of length 0.

If you want to create a list of a certain range you could do the following :

```
lst = [0] * 52
```

basically creating a list of 52 0's.

Although from what I understand you want to create a list containing multiple lists, you could do this like this

```
lst = [[0]] * 52
```

creating a list of 52 lists each containing a 0.

I think both way are less pythonic, you should be using the append function, when creating new members.

```
lst.append([0])
```

will append a [0] list to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
d = {}
i = 0
while i =< 50:
  d[i]=['1']
  i =+ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the teacher's structure

```
lst=[]
for index in range(0,51):
    lst.append(0)
print(lst)

y=(input("Enter a number: "))
while y.isdigit():
    y=(int)(y)
    lst[y]+=1
    y=(input("Enter a number: "))

print(lst)
```

However, more concise we can write

```
lst = [0] * 50
while True:
    y=(input("Enter a number: "))
    if not y.isdigit(): break
    y=(int)(y)
    if y < 50: lst[y]+=1

print(lst)
```

This creates a list with 50 zeros. We can then run the input section of the code. First we check if the input is a number, if it is not we `break`. Then if the number is less than 50, we increment the value at that index in the array.